# Brute-force graph isomorphism enumeration with prior information

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I would like to enumerate all possible mappings between two graphs. One way to achieve this is to generate all permutations of the vertex labels of one graph. In my situation, I also have more information: the potential mappings between the vertices. For example, suppose one graph has vertices {'1', '2'}, the other {'a', 'b'}, I also know that '1' maps to 'a', and '2' maps to either 'a' or 'b'.

- Give this extra information, how do I enumerate more efficiently?
- Is there a way to convert generating this mapping to a graph traversal problem on some product graph? Somehow I find attempting to think that way. For example, if we start from '1a', then we move to '2b'.

Comment: you might be interested in the VF2 algorithm, which I think could be adapted to your needs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743894/any-working-example-of-vf2-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Identifying graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism#Recognition_of_graph_isomorphism) is known to be an intrinsically computationally-complex activity, although the exact level is not known. Identifying all possible isomorphisms is obviously even more work.

Obviously, for efficiency's sake, you shouldn't bother matching vertices that have dissimilar attributes. So you should create independent shuffle lists for, say, [vertex degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)#Types_of_vertices) + [minimum cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) + [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)#Related_concepts). You should probably [identify cut points](https://web.archive.org/web/20130718095926/http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~mestre/class/2012s2/material/DFS.pdf) of degree $\ge 3$ also and prioritize their placement to force adjacent parts of the graph into correspondence, and reduce the task by division into smaller subgraphs by recursion.

Obviously any labelling information could further constrain which options are available, and distances to labelled entities as well as cutpoints will reduce and subdivide the task further.